# vue-google-chart GChart changing graph type with a button

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, charts, google-visualization

```
<GChart
    id="theChart"
    :type="newChartType"
    :data="chartData"
    :options="chartOptions()"
    :resize-debounce="500"
    :events="chartEvents"
    ref="gChart"
/>

<rev-button
    id="chart-button-1"
    @click="buttonClick"
>
</rev-button>
```

```
export default {
    name: 'RevChartWidget',
        components: {
            GChart
        },
    props: {
        chartData: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
        chartTitle: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: ''
        },
        chartType: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    setup(props) {
        let newChartType = 'LineChart'
        let pieHoleSize = 0.85
    
        if (props.chartData[0].length === 2) {
            newChartType = 'PieChart'
            
            if (props.chartType === 'PieChart') {
                pieHoleSize = 0.00
            }
        }

        let func = () => {
            let newChartType = 'LineChart'
            document.getElementById("chart").draw();
        }

        const chartOptions = () => {
            // options
            const options = {
                pieHole: pieHoleSize,
                // title
                titleTextStyle: { 
                    color: '#ffffff', 
                    fontSize: 16, 
                    fontName: 'Barlow' 
                },
                // horizontal axis
                hAxis: {
                    textStyle: {
                        color: '#ffffff',
                        fontName: 'Barlow',
                        fontSize: 12
                    },
                    slantedText: false,
                    minTextSpacing: 1
                },
                // vertical axis
                vAxis: {
                    textStyle: {
                        color: '#ffffff',
                        fontName: 'Barlow',
                        fontSize: 12
                    },
                    gridlines: {
                        count: 0
                    },
                    slantedText: false,
                    minTextSpacing: 1
                },
                // legend
                legend: {
                    textStyle: {
                        color: '#ffffff',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontName: 'Barlow',
                        bold: true,
                        italic: false
                    }
                },
                // tooltip
                tooltip: {
                    textStyle: {
                        color: '#000000',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontName: 'Barlow',
                        bold: true,
                        italic: false
                    }
                },
                // chart
                // width: 740,
                // height: 200,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                baselineColor: 'white'
            }
            
            const chart = {
                ...options,
                title: props.chartTitle
            }

            return chart
        }

        return {
            chartOptions,
            newChartType,
            func
        }
    },
    data(){
        return{
            buttonClick: () => {
                alert("test");
                var heading = document.getElementById("theChart");
                heading.setAttribute("type", "LineChart");
            },
            chartEvents: { // not currently working
                select: () => {
                    const table = this.$refs.gChart.chartObject;
                    const selection = table.getSelection();          
                    const onSelectionMessage = selection.length !== 0 ? 'was selected' : 'was diselected'
                    alert(onSelectionMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to have buttons for each type of chart that the user may want and then when you click the buttons it will update the type / refresh the graph with the new graph type. I've tried multiple ways of referencing and changing the GChart type by calling its id name and such but nothing has worked. I looked into the documentation and it seems that you should be able to create an instance of it using the custom @ready feature but I couldn't get it to work and don't even know if it would help for this...

Comment: thinking you need @ready in order to get a reference to the `ChartWrapper` object, on which you can use the `setChartType` method, after which the chart wrapper must be re-drawn...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, but fixed it by using methods section. Does your button recognize the click? If it doesn't recognize the click at all, you can try to make "methods" in export default section. Then include the buttonClick in the methods.

```
methods: {
    async buttonClick (id) {
      *What the button should do* 
    }
}
```